# Using pytest fixture from common test function

Tags: python, pytest

I have some `unittest`-based code that [currently looks like this](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/scuba/blob/9d0b6de35ff372abd36e1ea53b89cd03fa0051eb/tests/test_main.py):

```py
class TestMain(TestCase):
    def run_prog(self, args):
        with TemporaryFile() as stdout:
            old_stdout = sys.stdout
            try:
                main.main()
                stdout.seek(0)
                stdout_data = stdout.read()
            finally:
                sys.stdout = old_stdout
        return stdout_data

    def test_one(self):
        out = self.run_prog(...)

    def test_two(self):
        out = self.run_prog(...)

    def test_three(self):
        out = self.run_prog(...)
```

`run_prog` invokes the "main" program under test and manually captures its stdout.

I'm in the process of converting this project to `pytest`, but this last piece has pushed the limits of my understanding of pytest fixtures.

I understand that pytest has full support for [capturing stdout/stderr](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/capture.html) and I would like to leverage this.

The problem is, their examples work on a test-function level:

```py
def test_myoutput(capfd):
    do_something
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == "hello\n"
    assert captured.err == "world\n"
```

In my case, `run_prog` is used 42 times, so I'm trying to use the fixture starting at `run_prog` -- the calling functions ideally don't need to bother with `capsys`/`capfd`.

Is there a way to "invoke" the fixture from my `run_prog` helper? Or do I need to add `capfd` to all 42 tests and pass it to `run_prog`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define an autouse fixture that will store the `CaptureFixture` object (returned by the `capsys` fixture) as an instance property:

```
class TestMain(TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def inject_capsys(self, capsys):
        self._capsys = capsys

    def run_prog(self, args):
        main.main()
        return self._capsys.out

    def test_out(self):
        assert self.run_prog('spam') == 'eggs'
```

The `TestMain.inject_capsys` fixture will be rerun for each test, guaranteeing the test isolation (no output from `test_one` will be leaked in `test_two` etc).

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the class-level `autouse` fixtures, but it didn't feel quite right. Your answer confirms that it is the right way to go.

Comment: Also: Also: https://hackebrot.github.io/pytest-tricks/fixtures_as_class_attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight variation on [hoefling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442694/119527) that gives a little more control over the scope of the `capsys` fixture.

It uses [`request.getfixturevalue()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue) to retrieve the fixture at function invocation time:

```py
import pytest
import sys

class TestMain:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def inject_request(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def run_prog(self, message):
        capfd = self.request.getfixturevalue('capfd')

        sys.stdout.write(message)

        captured = capfd.readouterr()
        assert captured.out == message

    def test_one(self):
        self.run_prog("Hello world!")
```